# How does Gamora know the location of this object?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones, avengers-infinity-war

How does Gamora know the location of the

> Soul Stone?

Did I miss something or is this never explained? How does Gamora know the trial needed to acquire it?

Comment: It is not referenced in any other Guardians of the Galaxy movie.

Comment: “Did I miss something” — oerhaps. In the movie, Gamora says (I think in Nebula’s memory that Thanos plays in front of her) that she found a map to the Soul Stone, while searching for it on behalf of Thanos when she worked for him. “How does Gamora know the trial needed to acquire it?” I don’t think she does, not until Red Skull explains it. She laughs in surprise when she hears it, believing that Thanos has nothing he loves to sacrifice, and thus can’t claim it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: +1, and can you make your comment a full answer? I believe yours is the right answer.

Comment: Not sure why there is an impression of Gamora knowing about the trails because in the film there is no mention of her knowing anything about the trails and she never acted like she knew

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have sources other than my own understanding of the movie, but it's explained that:

> Gamora was sent on a mission by Thanos many years ago to find the Soul Stone. It's not explained **where** she acquired this information, just that she had, and that she was lying about not knowing where it was.

As for the trial:

> I don't believe she knew what the trial was until she and Thanos were told by the stone's keeper. My basis for this is her reaction; she goes from somber to mirth when she thinks there's no way for Thanos to complete the trial.

Answer (score 6):

I'm just going to expand what Paul D. Waite said in the comments to the question. From the movie:

> While interrogating / torturing Nebula, Thanos replays her memories, particularly the one where Gamora tells her that she found the map to the Soul Stone and burned it to ashes.

But Thanos obviously doesn't believe Gamora, saying something along the lines of:

> He brought her up and never trained her to lie, and that's why she (Gamora) is so bad at it. So Thanos is guessing that Gamora either didn't burn the map, or burned the map after committing to memory where the Soul Stone is.